# Django - No User matches the given query

Tags: django

Boa tarde, sou novo no Django e estou com o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não consigo acessar o admin. Já verifiquei a url diversas vezes e esta tudo correto.
Até um dia atras estava acessando o admin normalmente.

Answer (score -1):

2 coisas para vc verificar.

1. Conflito de rotas.
2. Se tem o admin na tupla INSTALLED_APPS no settings.py.

Comment: Hummm eu verifiquei as rotas e estão todas corretas. E no settings esta o admin. INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin'.

Comment: É a segunda vez que tenho este problema. Na primeira vez tive que criar um novo projeto e migrar todas as apps.

Comment: Pode colocar como está o seu urls.py?

Comment: urlpatterns = 
path('admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin'),  
path('login/', auth_views.login, name='login'),  
    path('logout/', auth_views.logout, name='logout'),  
    path('main/', include('main.urls'), name='main'),  
    path('cursos/', include('cursos.urls'), name='cursos'),  
    path('personal/', include('personal.urls'), name='personal'),  
    path('members/', include('members.urls'), name='members'),  
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls'), name='blog'),  
    path('shop/', include('shop.urls'), name='shop'),  
]

Comment: **from django.contrib import admin**                                          url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

Comment: url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
NameError: name 'url' is not defined

Comment: E não é somente o admin que não consigo acessar. Qualquer pagina retorna o erro da imagem.

Comment: O usuário está no banco de dados como admin?

Comment: existem 3 usuarios cadastrados.

Comment: O q vc está logado existe no banco de dados? **Já tentou entrar na guia como anonimo?**

Comment: Eu nem cheguei a logar!rs  tentar acessar pelo modo anonimo do chrome? Já e ocorre o mesmo erro!

Answer (score -1):

Resolvido. 
O problema estava quando eu realizava o logout.
Ao tentar abrir a tela de login, tinha uma middleware tentando acessar o request.user que já tinha sido apagado.
Obrigado Micael.
Abraços